# mysql group_concat in where

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem with the following query(if this is a duplicate question then i'm terribly sorry, but i can't seem to find anything yet that can help me):

```
SELECT d.*, GROUP_CONCAT(g.name ORDER BY g.name SEPARATOR ", ") AS members
FROM table_d AS d LEFT OUTER JOIN table_g AS g ON (d.eventid = g.id)
WHERE members LIKE '%p%';
```

MySQL apparently can't handle a comparison of GROUP_CONCAT columns in a WHERE clause.
So my question is very simple. Is there a workaround for this, like using sub-query's or something similar? I really need this piece of code to work and there is not really any alternative to use other than handling this in the query itself.

**EDIT 1:**

I won't show the actual code as this might be confidential, I'll have to check with my peers. Anyway, I just wrote this code to give you an impression of how the statement looks like although I agree with you that it doesn't make a lot of sense. I'm going to check the answers below in a minute, i'll get back to you then. Again thnx for all the help already!

**EDIT 2:**

Tried using `HAVING`, but that only works when i'm not using `GROUP BY`. When I try it, it gives me a syntax error, but when I remove the `GROUP BY` the query works perfectly. The thing is, i need the `GROUP BY` otherwise the query would be meaningless to me.

**EDIT 3:**

Ok, so I made a stupid mistake and put `HAVING` before `GROUP BY`, which obviously doesn't work. Thanks for all the help, it works now!

Comment: what is wrong with `g.name like '%peter%'`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

```
... HAVING members LIKE '%peter%'
```

`WHERE` applies the filter before the `GROUP_CONCAT` is evaluated; `HAVING` applies it later.

**Edit:**  I find your query a bit confusing.  It looks like it's going to get only one row with all of your names in a single string -- unless there's nobody in your database named Peter, it which case the query will return nothing.

Perhaps `HAVING` isn't really what you need here...

Comment: @dnagirl: the group_concat already has an alias in the select... it is `members` so @awm was completely correct.

Comment: You most certainly **can** use an alias in a having clause.  Try it!

Comment: @dnagirl: maybe you meant in the `WHERE` clause? because the `WHERE` clause does not accept aliases, and if so - you are correct

Comment: @BigFatBaby, @awm: objections withdrawn. I was confusing the restriction on aliases with that of the WHERE clause.

Comment: Well, `HAVING` does work except not when i also want to use GROUP BY.

Comment: nvm i didn't put `HAVING` after `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT ...
...
WHERE g.name = 'peter'
```

instead. Since you're just doing a simple name lookup, there's no need to search the derived field - just match on the underlying original field.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP_CONCAT` is an aggregate function.  You have to `GROUP BY something`.  If you just want all the rows that have `%peter%` in them try

```
SELECT d.*, g.name  
FROM table_d AS d 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table_g AS g 
  ON (d.eventid = g.id) 
WHERE g.name LIKE '%peter%';
```

Comment: that is not entirely correct. yes - `GROUP_CONCAT` is an aggregative function, but no - you are not required to `GROUP BY` something. MySQL simply groups all the result set into the same group if no `GROUP BY` statement was given, which may be the desired effect here.